# protobuf-net inheritance : derived class hides base class property

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual, protobuf-net

`protobuf-net proto2 c#`

I have a derived-class that re-defines the type by hiding the corresponding base-class property of the same name.

I wish to serialize a base-class instance and de-serialize as the derived-type :

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"BaseClassProto")]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(typeof(DerivedClass), 1000)]
public partial class BaseClass {
  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyProperty", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)] 
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"DerivedClassProto")] 
public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyProperty", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)] 
  public new MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
  }
}

public class Test {
  var baseObject = new BaseClass{ TestString = "TestBaseObject", TestInt = 1 };

  DerivedClass derivedObject;
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);
    Debug.WriteLine(stream.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    derivedObject = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);
  }
}
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   protobuf-net.dll but was not handled in user code 
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'BaseClass' to type 'DerivedClass'.

Why is `protobuf-net` attempting to cast `BaseClass` to `DerivedClass` ?

Shouldn't `protobuf-net` just deserialize the message directly to `DerivedClass` as per the proto annotations within `DerivedClass` ?

Also does hiding `BaseClass.IntProperty` also hide its `ProtoMember` annotation ?  thus allowing `proto index 1` to be re-defined in `DerivedClass` ?

EDIT TO ADD ADDITIONAL INFO :

Attempting a minimum-viable test-case , even if I redefine `DerivedClass` to be as simple as possible :

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"DerivedClassProto")] 
public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
}
```

I still find that serialize `BaseClass` / deserialize `DerivedClass` throws the same `System.InvalidCastException`

Further if I de-serialize into a reference of `object` type ( rather than `DerivedClass` ) the underlying type is `BaseClass`.  This explains the cast exception, but asks the question why is `ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>()` deserializing into an object of type `BaseClass` ?

Answer (score 2):

Different levels of hierarchy in protobuf-net are separate messages in .proto terms. The tags for a subclass are independent of the tags in the base class. Reusing a tag is not a concept between levels. I'm surprised the code shown actually works at all, as that seems to use tag 1 twice in a single level (once for the sub-type, once for the property - both on `MyBaseType`). This may be contributing to the confusing error.

Comment: argh that was a typo : i've edited to `[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(typeof(MyDerivedType), 1000)]`

Comment: my understanding is that `protobuf-net` by default will not automatically add to a sub-class message contract those `[ProtoMember]` fields defined  in the base class -- however, it will add them if base-class is decorated with `[ProtoInclude]`  -- is this correct ?

Comment: @BaltoStar in that case my suspicion would be a reflection bug in the library. Re-declared members are a royal PITA for reflection. Does it still happen if the second member is named differently?

Comment: @Balto from protobuf-net's perspective, the base type and the sub type are completely separate. It doesn't add them *to the sub type's contract* even when inheritance is defined. The base type worries about the things in the base type. The sub type worries about the things in the sub type.

Comment: Ok so if base-type and sub-type contracts are determined solely from base-class and sub-class respectively, then what is the purpose of `[ProtoInclude]` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar to allow a path to get to all the levels that need handling, especially during deserialization (although it applies equally during serialization, but at least you can use .BaseType etc). So there is some code that knows about the fields that the base type has, and knows the expected subtypes; that code gets invoked, and does its thing and hands off to the next level, and so on. Both levels are needed, but they are separate.

Comment: hmmm trying to narrow this down to minimum viable use-case : my tests show that even for a sub-class that doesn't add any additional fields to its base-class ( and no overrides or hides either ), serialization of base-type object and de-serialization to sub-type still throws an `System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: so a sub-type's serialized bytes start with a base-type message ( as per base-type contract ) and then append a sub-type message ( as per sub-type contract ) ?  the base-type fields are marked with tags that each include the field index & primitive-type, and followed by a tag that includes the sub-type index ( as defined in [ProtoInclude] on the base-type ) that precedes the actual sub-type message ?